# MinIO Spring Boot. java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, minio, socketexception

Cant upload images sometimes on MinIO bucket. Sometimes it works correctly, sometimes its throwing this exception.

file is MultipartFile

```
try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            String tempPath = TEMP_FOLDER + "/" + originalFileName;
            PutObjectArgs args = PutObjectArgs.builder().
                    bucket(minioBucket).object(tempPath).
                    stream(inputStream, inputStream.available(), -1L).
                    headers(defaultHeaders).contentType(file.getContentType()).build();
            minioClient.putObject(args);

        }
```

Thanks for help in advance